# Android, show and hide menu items issue

Tags: android, menu

I am building an native Android application.
I have a menu and i want to show and hide items, depending on the person logged in (child or parent).

I save the login information of the person, in shared preferences. This is working fine. I get the info of the person logged in.

The problem is the menu, it only works sometime.

I am a beginner and any help would be appreciated.

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String auth_user, toolbox_access, results_access;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
    auth_user = (preferences.getString("auth_settings", ""));
    toolbox_access = (preferences.getString("toolbox_access", ""));
    results_access = (preferences.getString("results_access", ""));
}

public void Toolbar(){
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.ic_reorder_black_24dp);
    toolbar.setOverflowIcon(drawable);
    //Toolbar title
    TextView toolbar_title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
    toolbar_title.setText(getString(R.string.action_exercise));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
     if(auth_user == "Parent"){
           MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_card_list);
           item.setVisible(false);
    }

    if(auth_user == "Child"){
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_card_list);
        item.setVisible(true);
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.action_login) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
    }
    if (id == R.id.action_exercise) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ExerciseListActivity.class));
    }
    if (id == R.id.action_top_problems) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ExercisePostActivity.class));
    }
    if (id == R.id.action_test) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, TestActivity.class));
    }
    if (id == R.id.action_exercise2) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, AssessmentDailyActivity.class));
    }
    if (id == R.id.action_ocdlist) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, OcdListActivity.class));
    }
    if (id == R.id.action_card_list) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, CardActivity.class));
    }

    if (id == R.id.action_results) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ResultsActivity.class));
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.equals()` to compare Strings for equality.

```
if ("Parent".equals(auth_user)) {
```